# RuntimeError: Invalid quantization params for op GATHER at index 2 in subgraph 0

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite

I use tflite convert tf.keras h5 model to tflite, and quantized model.

```
    converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model_file(h5, custom_objects=custom_objects)

    converter.representative_dataset = tf.lite.RepresentativeDataset(
        representative_dataset_gen)
    # converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]
    converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.OPTIMIZE_FOR_SIZE]
    converter.inference_input_type = tf.lite.constants.QUANTIZED_UINT8
    converter.inference_output_type = tf.lite.constants.QUANTIZED_UINT8

    tflite_model = converter.convert()
    open("{}.tflite".format(out), "wb").write(tflite_model)
```

than cause the error:
RuntimeError: Invalid quantization params for op GATHER at index 2 in subgraph 0

does tflite not support GATHER op? how to fix it?

Comment: Hello, any track? I am getting this kind of issue, RuntimeError: Invalid quantization params for op RESHAPE at index 0 in subgraph 0.

Comment: The error message means that the gather wasn't quantized. Gather supports quantization in TFLite. Can you file a github issue with reproduce steps.